# Tracking checkboxes with dynamic ID on HubSpot form with Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, hubspot

I've set up form tracking on GTM, but I'm now having issues with tracking specifically form submissions where the opt-in subscription checkbox has also been checked. I'd set up a trigger to fire when the checkbox is true and the form submit button is clicked, which originally worked when I tested it in preview mode. I discovered that the ID attribute of the checkbox is dynamic, which is why my custom javascript variable no longer works. This is what I have currently (which worked before the last four digits of the ID changed):

```
function() {
var checkbox = document.getElementById("LEGAL_CONSENT.subscription_type_6337149-8b3f66b8-292e-411d-a20e-f08f28554e60_7739");
return checkbox.checked || false;
}
```

Is there an easy workaround for this, such as selecting the element by an ID that starts with the portion that doesn't change?

EDIT:

I've replaced it with the following, but it's still not firing:

```
function() {
var checkbox = document.querySelector('[id^="LEGAL_CONSENT.subscription_type_6337149-8b3f66b8-292e-411d-a20e-f08f28554e60_"]');
return checkbox.checked || false;
}
```

HTML of subscription checkbox:

```
<input id="LEGAL_CONSENT.subscription_type_6337149-8b3f66b8-292e-411d-a20e-f08f28554e60_9479" class="hs-input" type="checkbox" name="LEGAL_CONSENT.subscription_type_6337149" value="true" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-1.2.1:0.$LEGAL_CONSENT=1subscription_type_6337149.$LEGAL_CONSENT=1subscription_type_6337149.$LEGAL_CONSENT=1subscription_type_6337149.0.0.0.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

The below function should work as you are using the class name of the element which should not change dynamically.

```
 function() {
var checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName(“hs-input”);    
 return checkbox.checked || false;
}
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer